# The correct translation for 'toilets'?

Tags: traducción

I'm trying to figure out how to ask where the toilets are if I'm in a restaurant. Of course I would start with '¿Dónde está...' but then I'm not sure whether to say 'lavabo', 'baño', 'servicios' or 'tocador'. Can all of these words be understood as 'toilets'? Which of them is the most formal and which is the most common?

Comment: The answer there is correct. As an Spaniard, all but the last would sound not extrange, but most people always use baño.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*¿Dónde está el baño?* Would be universally understood to be asking for the room where the toilet is located.  It is neither vulgar nor extremely delicate.  If you just want to keep it simple, this is what you will use.

Answer (score 4):

Another **very** common alternative (in Spain at least) is *¿Dónde están los aseos?* Since an *aseo* is basically a bathroom without the bathtub/shower, it could be considered more correct in a restaurant setting, etc. Having said that, *¿Dónde está el baño?* or *¿Dónde están los servicios?* would be universally understood and no one would think twice about it.